# Scaling SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have created various SKSPriteNode's in a scene. The node is circle. I was wondering how I would be able to change the node's size to maybe 2/3's or 3/4's of it's original size depending on a condition I have. I know I have to use the scale method/function but i'm not 100% sure how I would implement 2/3's or 3/4's of it's current size into the parameters :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method/Function as such:

```
func scalePlayer(percentage: CGFloat)
{
    player.xScale = percentage
    player.yScale = percentage
}
```

then implement during condition as such:

```
scalePlayer(percentage: 0.75)
```

Comment: This is not necessary since SKNode already has a method that sets both x and y scale. So you can do it like this `mySprite.setScale(0.75)`